# Render graphics using Doubles in Graphics2D

Tags: java, rendering

Currently, I have a JFrame for my game to render in, and I'm using Graphics2D for drawing (The games graphics are fairly simple 2D sprites). However, my delta variable is a double, and all of the Graphics 2D methods (And Grpahics) use int. I tried to type cast the delta to an int, but it just rounds down to 0. So my question is, how can I render graphics using Graphics2D in Java with coordinates that are doubles. Can I convert it to work with Graphics2D if there is no built in way? Or, is there a graphics library that can support doubles for coordinates?

Comment: How do you intend to light a fraction of a pixel on your computer monitor?

Comment: It can be done with sub-pixel accurate rendering and antialiasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class uses integer coordinates for all operations, but [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) provides API with float and double accuracy. You can use [Graphics2D.draw(Shape)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw%28java.awt.Shape%29) and [Graphics2D.fill(Shape)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill%28java.awt.Shape%29) to get sub-pixel accuracy in rendering. You should also probably enable antialiasing for the Graphics2D object.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.draw(new Line2D.Double(10.5, 10.5, 20.5, 20.5));
}
```

Alternatively you can scale, rotate and translate Graphics2D object or manipulate the [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) directly. This might be needed if you want to draw images to double coordinates.

Comment: I was actually thinking about checking out Shape & using that. Thanks the for the answer!